# Log In feature creates KeyError when username doesn't exist - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a game which begins with a log in feature

The user can 'Log in (A) or Create an account(B)'

My issue is if the user logs in with a username which doesn't exist I get a KeyError: "(whatever username they typed)"

[image: Full Error shown]

**Expected Result:**
I would like the code to output 'User doesn't exist' if this happens.

The problem can be reproduced with this code and typing 'A' to log in and entering a random username which doesn't exist.

```
users = {} # Currently empty list called Users. Stores all log ins
global status
status = ""

def LogIn():#Function is called Log In. Can be called at any time.
    status = input("Log in (A) or Create an account(B) - Enter 'A' or 'B' ")   # asks for log in information
    status = status.upper()
    if status == "A":
        oldUser() #Already has an account
    elif status == "B":
        newUser() #Would like to make a new account
        return status #Moves on to the function named status

def newUser(): # Creating an account.
    CreateUsername = input("Create username: ") #Enter a what your username is

    if CreateUsername in users: # check if login name exists in the list
        print ("\n Username already exists!\n")
    else:
        createPassw = input("Create password: ")
        users[CreateUsername] = createPassw # add login and password
        print("\nUser created!\n")     

def oldUser():
    username = input("Enter username: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")

    # check if user exists and login matches password
    if passw == users[username]:
      print ("Login successful!\n")
      print('Game begins')
    else:
        print ("\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password!\n")

while status != "q":            
    status = LogIn()
```

Extra Info: more context of how the log in feature works.
[image: More Context]

Comment: First, you must include the error message inside the question, not in an image. (it's usually included in a code block)

Comment: Regarding the question -- it appears that you know how to check if the key is in a dict. So just do that before accessing the key.

Comment: This is a logic error.  This is happening I think when a user chooses to log in for a user who doesn't exist already.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you it is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by altering

```
def oldUser():
    username = input("Enter username: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")

    # check if user exists and login matches password
    if username not in users:
      print ("Username doesn't exist")
      print('Game begins')
    elif passw == users[username]:
        print('Log In successful')
    else:
        print ("\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password!\n")

while status != "q":            
    status = LogIn()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because you're trying to access the `users` dictionary with a key that isn't in the dictionary. The key you're using is the username of the user. Therefore, when there isn't a user in the dictionary with that username you receive the `KeyError`

An alternative to using `try` and `except` would be to restructure your dictionary to be an array of user dictionaries, with each user dictionary containing the keys `username` and `password`

Answer (score 0):

Look into using python's `try` and `except`. These exist to help us handle errors when they arise while customizing the way you handle those errors. So for your specific question, give this a shot:

```
def oldUser():
   username = input("Enter username: ")
   passw = input("Enter password: ")

# check if user exists and login matches password
   try:
     if passw == users[username]:
        print ("Login successful!\n")
        print('Game begins')
   except:
      print ("\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password!\n")
```